# Checking for (x,y) in two 1D arrays one x and one y in Ruby

Tags: ruby

INTRO:
I am trying to program Snakes in Ruby in order to get myself more familiar with Ruby which I just recently started to learn because of its reputation.

So I saved all the coordinates of the Snake in and two arrays one for all the X coordinates and one for all the Y coordinates like this `x=[2,0,0]`and `y=[2,0,0]`. When the snakes eats food a new value is added to both arrays like this `x[f]=y[f-1] and y[f]=y[f-1]` So every part of the snake inherits the position of the part before. So far so good. But then I realized that the food which is placed through the `rand()` command some times is on the same position as the a part of the snake.

PROBLEM:
That is where my problem is. I tried to fix it like this:

```
while randomNumberIsSnake == true  
 if $x.include? randomX  
  if $y.include? randomY
   randomX = 2 + rand(18)
   randomY = 2 + rand(18)
  else
  randomNumberIsSnake = false
  end
 else
  randomNumberIsSnake = false
 end
end
```

To check if the X coordinates of the food is equal to the X coordinate of a part of the snake (in the array). If that is true than it also checks if the Y coordinate is in the Y array. It will then get a new number till that isn't the case anymore.

It seemed to work just right till I looked at it again and found that bug that if the `$y.include? randomY`and `$x.include? randomX`both return true it doesn't necessarily mean that the food is on the same coordinates as a part of the snake but rather if the food was (4,4) and the snake has a part on (4,8) and a part on (8,4) it will also return true. Which creates a situation like this.
     -------#
     -@-- #
     -------#
     #####
Where @ even though clearly not on the line of #'s still will make the code return true.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to rephrase the code in order to avoid that or would that require to have only one 2D array and not two 1D arrays. Like I mentioned earlier I am still a leaner in Ruby and there for every help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The solution below worked perfectly so, no need to answer it again. I am also sorry for the very long text, it was my first question ever asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your checker like this one:

```
coordinates = loop do
  randomX = 2 + rand(18)
  randomY = 2 + rand(18)
  randomNumberIsSnake = false
  $x.size.times do |index|
    randomNumberIsSnake = true if $x[index] == randomX && $y[index] == randomY
  end
  break [randomX, randomY] unless randomNumberIsSnake
end
```

Then in your coordinates local variable you'll have this values.

But I'd recommend you to store all free cell for current moment. Then take one randomly and remove from this array. If for some step array is empty there is no free cells at all. This solution is possible if that's not huge amount of cells.

Comment: Does the  `break [randomX, randomY]` change anything about the way I can call the variables?

Comment: @TobiasWilfert in this case it just returns an array with two elements inside.